# Яндекс Деньги API CURL

Tags: php, curl, yandex-money

пытаюсь сформировать вот такой запрос по документации Yandex Money API

https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/dg/reference/request-access-token-docpage/

```
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://money.yandex.ru/oauth/authorize');
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length: 191'));
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "client_id=44547**************************************EBB590&response_type=code&redirect_url=https://mysite.com&scope=account-info operation-history");
$data = curl_exec($curlInit);
curl_close($curlInit);
print_r($data);
```

При отправке POST запроса идет вечная загрузка, корректно ли я составил запрос, подскажите

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Length` лучше не указывать. `cURL` его сам корректно посчитает. Аналогично заголовок `Content-Type` сам `cURL` выставляет при использовании `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Собственно, в этом корень наблюдаемого эффекта бесконечной загрузки. Вы заголовком `Content-Length` утверждаете, что хотите передать 191 байт полезной нагрузки, а `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` у вас всего 147 байт (если предположить, что важные данные вы заменили на звёздочки один-к-одному). А поскольку http сервер видит, что вы заявили к передаче больше данных чем он на данный момент получил - значит вас надо подождать. А вы ждёте его, потому что уже вручную сломали логику `cURL`, он отправил все данные и ждёт ответ.

И ой неправильно вы `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` формируете. Если хотите передавать параметр строкой - то вы должны это делать корректно, предварительно выполнив требуемые по стандарту преобразования данных. Куда лучше поручить преобразование специально-обученной функции `http_build_query`:

```
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    'client_id' => '44547**************************************EBB590',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'redirect_url' => 'https://mysite.com',
    'scope' => 'account-info operation-history',
]));
```

В `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` можно передать и сразу массив, но тогда будет сформирован `multipart/form-data` `Content-Type`. Для многих систем в этом нет различий, но надо проверять с конкретной. Если требуется `x-www-form-urlencoded` - то как я уже показал нужен `http_build_query` или собирать данные вручную с `urlencode`